# how to insert string data into table as different column data in a row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How to insert string data into table in column data of one row.  I have string as :

```
 data= pawan,123,jhs,abc@gmail
```

and i want to insert this as

```
insert into table values(pawan,123,jhs,abc@gmail)
```

Comment: Will this String always contain four columns separated by comma or it may increase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have only four columns separated by comma in string:

```
 INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data_string, ',',1), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data_string, ',',0)) + 1), ',', ''),
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data_string, ',',2), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data_string, ',',1)) + 1), ',', ''),
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data_string, ',',3), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data_string, ',',2)) + 1), ',', ''),
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data_string, ',',4), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data_string, ',',3)) + 1), ',', '')
```

Comment: In last line  REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data_string, ',',4), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data_string, ',',2)) + 1), ',', '')
            )   i changed  REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data_string, ',',4), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data_string, ',',3)) + 1), ',', '')
            )  then its absolutely inserting correct data