# How to insert string into different columns in database table?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-server, string

Basically I've made an string out of `pdf` file, and that string contains comma-separated values which I now need to insert into different columns in table. 
I would try similar question's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452150/how-to-insert-string-data-into-table-as-different-column-data-in-a-row), but I don't get it for my need.

I already tried exploding that string into an array, so that comma is each element separator like so:

```
$array = explode(',', $text);
```

But since I have just 3 columns into table, I need to sort that values into those columns, so that each third string would go into first column and all following it into following columns. I tried doing it like so:

```
$duzina=count($array);
        for($i=0;$i<$duzina;$i++) {
            if ($i = 0 && $i < 3) {
                $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `surname`, `email`) VALUES
                (
                    '" . trim($array[$i]) . "',
                    '" . addslashes($array[$i + 1]) . "',
                    '" . addslashes($array[$i + 2]) . "'
                )
            ");
            }
            if ($i/3 == 0) {// has found a 3rd,6th,9th element of an $array

                $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `surname`, `email`) VALUES
                (
                    '" . trim($array[$i]) . "',
                    '" . addslashes($array[$i + 1]) . "',
                    '" . addslashes($array[$i + 2]) . "'
                )
            ");
            } else {
                $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `surname`, `email`) VALUES
                (
                    '" . trim($array[$i]) . "',
                    '" . addslashes($array[$i + 1]) . "',
                    '" . addslashes($array[$i + 2]) . "'
                )
            ");
            }
```

But all it does is inserting first 3 elements of `$array`. Please help

Comment: convert $i/3 == 0 to $i%3 == 0

Comment: You probably need only 1 insert block and no conditions at all if you use something like `$i += 3` instead of `$i++`. I would have to see the data to be sure though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use prepared statements.
Restructure your data to be meaningful in code(useful for debugging)
Loop wisely(increment by 3)

Note, code below is not fieldtested, just proof of concept.

```
$array = loadpdfwhatever();
$length = count($array);

// Restructure the raw data to be meaningful to a human. Can be skipped,
// but this will help you debugging in + 3 weeks from now :-)
$restructured = [];
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i+=3) { // note the $i+3 to increment by 3.
    $restructured[] = ['name'=> $array[$i],
                       'surname'=> $array[$i+1],
                       'email'=> $array[$i+2]];
}


// Using prepared statements we only have to build up the query once.
// Makes code faster and more efficient.
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `surname`, `email`) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? ) ")) {
    foreach($restructured as $insert) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'sss',$insert['name'],
                                           $insert['surname'],
                                           $insert['email']); 
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't tell you how thankful I am for this answer of yours :)

Comment: You're welcome. Learn the lesson when importing raw data, to make it meaningful to YOU. Not tot he code. To you in the future, when you come back in 6 months :-). When you have that approach stuff will be easier for you to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

no the rest of division get by `%` not `/`, so replace this:

```
if ($i/3 == 0) {
```

with

```
if ($i%3 == 0) {
```

Comment: It is still inserting first tree elements, more than 1200 times. And I don't know how my script did that because  all inserting is limited by number of elements in `$array` with this part of code : `for($i=0;$i<$duzina;$i++)` and `$duzina` is `count($array)`..

Comment: @Ognj3n can you provide your array?

Comment: or what $duzina equal?

Comment: Thanks a lot folks, Michael Dibbets already solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

2 things :

first use if / elseif /else

```
if ($i = 0 && $i < 3) {
    ...
}
elseif ($i%3 == 0) {
    ...
}
else
{
    ....
}
```

Second :

its `$i%3 == 0` and not `$i/ 3 == 0`