# Insert string as row in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, insert

I have some strings in an audit table that describe an entire row that was deleted.  Ie, they look like:

```
'(029e99b4-6ea2-46e4-a89d-91d96aff41c4/4/5b,029e99b4-6ea2-46e4-a89d-91d96aff41c4,029e99b4-6ea2-46e4-a89d-91d96aff41c4,M4,short_rainy,54,Coffee,1,,2,,,2015-11-09,2,,,,,2,,)'
```

They were creating using the `ROW()` function in the useful script described [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger).

Now, I want to insert them into the table they came from.  It still has the same schema, so each column in the string should correspond to the correct column in the table.  How can I do that?

My apologies if this has been asked already - I looked around and only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452150/how-to-insert-string-data-into-table-as-different-column-data-in-a-row) question, which doesn't seem workable in my case because I have so many columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to the table type before inserting:

```
insert into t
values
    ((
        029e99b4-6ea2-46e4-a89d-91d96aff41c4/4/5b,
        029e99b4-6ea2-46e4-a89d-91d96aff41c4,
        029e99b4-6ea2-46e4-a89d-91d96aff41c4,
        M4,short_rainy,54,Coffee,1,,2,,,2015-11-09,2,,,,,2,,
    )::t)
```